# Vaadin data model interface relationship explanation

Tags: java, vaadin

This is the interface relationships of Vaadin data model, which is found in Book of Vaadin.

[image]

What is the meaning of the dot at one end of the line joining `Container` and `Item`? As far as I know, a diamond shape at one end of a line represents the ownership and the class at the diamond end is the owner. In this case, it doesn't feel like `Item` is the owner of the `Container` so this dot cannot be a replacement for the diamond.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [API of the `Item`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Item.html), there is no reference back to the container.  The `Container` holds `0..n` items.  While the arrows assemble the inheritance hierarchy, I'd put the rest of the diagram into the area of artistic freedom.  At least it is consistent.